# Can't run my pyinstaller made .exe app with PyQt5 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, pyqt

On Win10 64bit I installed PyQt5_5.4.1 for Python3.4.3. I need 3.4.3 for supporting XP clients and this is the last version that can be installed on XP. PyQt5 installed itself in python3.4.3 folder `C:\Python34` and I can see it in PATH `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5`

When I run my script with `python myscript.py` everything is fine, the gui window shows. However, when I try to run an .exe file from that script created with `pyinstaller` like this `pyinstaller myscript.py --onefile` I get an error:

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
This application failed to start because it 
could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

This code I have in myscript.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
```

Is there a fix for this problem? I tried reinstaling PyQt5 but no luck.

Comment: We're having the same problem in our application, we tried building on Windows 10 rather than on Windows 7 but this didn't help. Also it seems like it works on some Win10 systems but not on others. PyQt version: 5.10 Python version: 3.6

Comment: pyinstaller just sucks. And the more saddest part is it is the best available tool in python environment. I spent my weeks to generate fully exetubale file from my big python project with no result. So this makes python sucks :/

Answer (score 0):

Make a hook file in your project directory. Name it *hook-PyQt5.py* for example:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import qt_plugins_binaries
# Fixed the issue: could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".
binaries = qt_plugins_binaries('platforms', 'PyQt5')
```

In the Pyinstaller spec file, add a parameter

> hookspath=['./']

to Analysis object:

```
a = Analysis(
    ...
    hookspath=['./'],
    ...
)
```

or specifiy an argument "--additional-hooks-dir" to commandline if you use PyInstaller directly.

```
python -m PyInstaller --additional-hooks-dir="./" <your-script>
```